# Spectral measure of a unitary operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

The following is an Exercise of Conway's operator theory:

1-Show that if $A$ is hermitian operator, then $U=\text{exp}({iA})$ is unitary.

2- Show that every unitary can be so written.

3-Find the spectral measure of the unitary in terms of that of the hermitian operator.

proof: 1-The first claim is clear.

2- I think the second is false, based on Theorem 2.1.12 of Murphy's operator theory:

[image]

And also The following from Takesaki's Operator theory:
[image]

3- There is a unique spectral measure $E$ correspondence to $*-$ homomorphism $C(\sigma(A)) \to B(H)$ and $U =\int e^{i\lambda} dE(\lambda)$.

Is it correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second claim is indeed true.  Take $H = -i\; \log(U)$, where $\log$ is any branch of the natural logarithm that is a bounded Borel function on the unit circle.

Comment: Not in general, if $\sigma(U) = \Bbb T$, then there is not any self-adjoint operator $A$ that $U=exp(iA)$.

Comment: What's wrong with the one I specified?  Take e.g. the principal branch of log.

Comment: $(-\infty, 0] \not \subset D(\log)$. $D$ means the domain of $\log$

Comment: It is defined there (if we want it to be), it is just not continuous.  But you can use the functional calculus for bounded Borel functions.

Comment: I added some things to this question.

Comment: The theorem from Murphy is for a C*-algebra, and the one from Takesaki is for $C(\Gamma)$.  In both of those cases you are restricted to continuous functions.  But in this case you don't need $H$ to be a **continuous** function of $U$: any self-adjoint operator is OK.

Comment: It seems to me that the distinction is whether or not there is an  element $A$ in the algebra for which $U=e^{iA}$. The Borel functional calculus gives you what you want in the general context of operators on a Hilbert space, but the operator may not be in the $C^{\star}$ algebra. But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @T.A.E.  That's exactly it.  The Borel functional calculus for a bounded normal operator $U$ gives you something in the von Neumann algebra generated by $U$, not necessarily in the C* algebra.

Comment: I can not image how define a function on a set that does not intersect with its domain. For example what is $y$, when $y=\log (-1)$?

Comment: Any odd multiple of $i\pi$, take your pick.

Comment: @niki One defines $\log: \mathbb T \to \mathbb C$ as follows $\log(e^{i\theta})=i\theta$, where $-\pi<\theta\leq \pi$. This is not a continuous function but it is a Borel function on the circle so one can apply it a unitary operator $U$.

Comment: @JankoBracic : Thanks.

Comment: @niki I see that you are studying Conway's book, however in my opinion Pedersen's book Analysis Now is better in the sense that it is more trustable (and also more demanding exercises in that book have hints).

Comment: @JankoBracic: I downloaded this book. It seems be helpful. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the third claim is correct with the spectral representation

$$A=\int_{\sigma(A)} \lambda \ \mathrm{d}E(\lambda)$$

Comment: Also I mean it.

Comment: If it is not obvious, I would encourage you to write $A=\int_{\sigma(A)} \lambda \ \mathrm{d}E(\lambda)$. 

If $A$ is a unitary operator (thus $\sigma(A) \subset \mathbb{T}$) then by using the pullback measure argument (and by changing variables, see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) we could write $$A=\int_{\sigma(A)} \lambda \ \mathrm{d}E(\lambda) = \int_{[0, 2\pi)}e^{i\lambda} \ \mathrm{d}E^{\prime}(\lambda),$$
where $E^{\prime}$ is a spectral measure defined on a Borel sigma algebra over $[0, 2\pi)$ and was obtained from $E$ by the pull-back argument.

Comment: @mgn, thanks for the suggestion. In this case $A$ is a hermitian operator and $U=\text{exp}({iA})$ is a unitary operator.